# Excel 2016 transpose/pivot/unique

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to accomplish the following in Excel 2016:
I receive a table that has a list of the student id in Column A, the name of the course in Column B, the term the student took the course in Column C and the grade the student received in Column D (example below as "Example Table")
What I need to do is create a new table where column A is the student id (unique, no duplicates), row 1 is the courses that students have taken (all the courses in the exported file) and the grade each student received for the course next to the student ID and under the course name (example below as "Example Output")
Is this possible?

```
Example Table
Student_No  Course  Term    Grade
Student_1   ENG_111 Fal_2014    A
Student_1   MATH_202    Sum_2014    B
Student_1   IT_309  Fal_2014    B
Student_2   MATH_202    Win_2015    C
Student_3   LANG_222    Fal_2014    F
Student_3   LANG_322    Win_2015    W
Student_4   IT_100  Fal_2014    B
Student_4   IT_200  Win_2015    B
Student_4   ECON_100    Sum_2015    B
Student_4   MATH_300    Fal_2015    W
Student_5   ENG_111 Sum_2015    C
Student_5   MATH_202    Fal_2015    C
```

Example Output

```
ENG_111 MATH_202    IT_309  LANG_222    LANG_322    IT_100  IT_200  ECON_100    MATH_300
Student_1   A   B   B   N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
Student_2   N/A C   N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
Student_3   N/A N/A N/A F   W   N/A N/A N/A N/A
Student_4   N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A B   B   B   W
Student_5   C   C   N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following array formula, confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$13,MATCH($H2&I$1,$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0)),"")
```

[image]

About how to create the H Column and I1:Q1 Row, follow these steps:

For H Column, Copy A2:A13 to H Column and go to **Data**- **Remove Duplicates** option.

[image]

Get the result:

[image]

For I1:Q1 Row, copy B2:B13 to I Column and go to **Data**- **Remove Duplicates** option.

[image]

Then **Copy** the data in I column and select I1 and Paste as **Transpose**.

[image]

Then delete data in I2:I10, you will get the result.

[image]